# pass long file argument from batch script to bash script in windows with cygwin

Tags: windows, bash, shell, batch-file, cygwin

I am following this post:

http://blog.dotsmart.net/2011/01/27/executing-cygwin-bash-scripts-on-windows/

I need to execute a batch file with an argument and pass this argument to a bash script. The argument is a long file name with spaces, something like FILE WITH SPACES.xlsx.

In Windows:

`c> program.cmd "FILE WITH SPACES.xlsx"` # Windows adds the quotes to complete the name of the file.

The batch script must pass the name of the file "FILE WITH SPACES.xlsx" to a .sh script, something like this:

```
# program.sh "FILE WITH SPACES.xlsx"
```

Here is the problem, the file is passed without the quotes:

```
# program.sh FILE WITH SPACES.xlsx
```

The script program.sh has:

```
#!/bin/sh
anyprogram "$1"
```

The quotes are not passed and the program `anyprogram` doesn't locate the file FILE WITH SPACES.xlsx.

i tried escaping the " with \ but not work:

```
#!/bin/sh
anyprogram "\"$1"\"
```

Also, with:

```
#!/bin/sh
anyprogram '"$1"'
```

None looks to work, any suggestion?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. The args are not inside the batch file, those args are dynamic.

Comment: Within your .sh script you could try `in=\"$*\"` then `echo $in`.

Comment: Can you include in your question the line in the batch file where the call to the `.sh` file is being done?

Comment: Replace `$i` by `$*` or (when the call is correct) `$1`.

Comment: @MCND I used the same code of blog post:

http://blog.dotsmart.net/2011/01/27/executing-cygwin-bash-scripts-on-windows/

Comment: @walterA, thanks, my mistake in the example.

Comment: @Paul, Doesn't work also.

Comment: @rojo i tried and doesn't work.

Comment: The first line says that you have a path \bin (windows knows that a / can be replaced by \) and expects a sh.exe in that folder. You can the script without that line. Maybe try an `echo $1` and (when your script has the wrong extension like bat or cmd) `echo %1%`.

Answer (score 2):

Batch files can be tricky with the way they handle double-quotes, and adding Bash variables can make things even trickier.  Here is a solution that I believe solves your specific issue:

Batch file location: C:\Users\Jamey\Desktop\blah.bat

Batch file contents:

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO I AM A BATCH FILE.
CD C:\Users\Jamey\Desktop
ECHO TESTING > %1
TYPE %1
ECHO.
SET scriptpath=/cygdrive/c/users/jamey/desktop
C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe -c "$scriptpath/program.sh "%1""
```

Bash script location: C:\Users\Jamey\Desktop\program.sh

Bash script contents:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "I AM A BASH SCRIPT."
echo "A WINDOWS BATCH FILE TOLD ME TO SAY THIS: $1"
echo
ls -l "$1"
echo
cat "$1"
echo
rm -v "$1"
```

Here is the cmd.exe output from running blah.bat "FILE NAME WITH SPACES.txt":

```
C:\Users\Jamey\Desktop>blah.bat "FILE NAME WITH SPACES.txt"
I AM A BATCH FILE.
TESTING

I AM A BASH SCRIPT.
A WINDOWS BATCH FILE TOLD ME TO SAY THIS: FILE NAME WITH SPACES.txt

-rwxrwx---+ 1 Jamey None 10 Sep 24 09:05 FILE NAME WITH SPACES.txt

TESTING

removed 'FILE NAME WITH SPACES.txt'
```

Alternately, if you replaced 'rm -v' with 'cygstart', "FILE NAME WITH SPACES.txt" would open in Notepad.  Same goes for Excel with .xlsx extensions.  I hope this answers your question!

Comment: I don't know why this question or my comment got downvoted. From my perspective, I answered the question pretty accurately.

Comment: I've upvoted -- your response is correct (and helped me to solve an identical problem). 

One note: it would be prudent to use single-quotes to surround the script parameter instead of doubles in order to avoid bash messing with backslashes etc. (I  pass a DOS path+filename from my batch file to my script then convert to unix format within the bash script using cygpath.)